# Table columns get cropped @ lower resolutions (800 x 600 and lower)

Tags: html, css, html-table

Well, I've got a really annoying problem: my table columns keep getting cut off at lower resolutions, particularly @ 800 x 600.

Here's an example of how it should look like (1920 x 1080):

[image: https://flic.kr/p/uy9Y2L]

And here's how it looks @ 800x600:

[image: https://flic.kr/p/uQJBQM]

EDIT:

html:

```
<div class="tablewrapper">
  <div class="center2">    
    <div class="component">   
        <table>
            <tr>
            <c:forEach items="${nombreColumnas}" var="columnas" >
                <th><c:out value="${columnas}"/></th>
            </c:forEach>
            </tr>  
            <c:forEach items="${suscripciones}" var="item" >
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${item.idSuscripcion}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${item.nombreCompleto}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${item.fechaUltimoPago}"/></td> 
                <td><a href="">
                        <button type="button" class="button-table"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Asignar apadrinado</button></a></td>                   
                </tr>                                     
            </c:forEach>
        </table>     
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.tablewrapper {
display: inline-block;

position: relative;
margin-left: 10%;
width:80%;
max-width: 80%; }     

.center2 {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin-right: 100px;
width:100%;
max-width: 100%;}
```

What could it be?

Comment: Please post your code so that we can have a look to the issue and help/suggest accordingly.

Comment: That is not nearly enough code. I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/hdL6w0mp/) out of it, but it doesn't behave like your screenshots. So can you create an example that demonstrates the issue?